# Find the right degree of the Maclaurin polynomial of $e^x$

Tags: taylor-expansion, error-function

Here is my question:

> What degree Maclaurin polynomial of $e^x$ must be taken to guarantee an estimate of $e$ to within $1 \times 10^{-6}?$

I know that the error term is:
$$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1} \qquad \text{for some } c \in]0,x[$$

Here is what I did:

Since we know that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$, we have:

$$R_n(x)=\frac{e^c}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1} < 10^{-6}$$

Now, since $c \in]0,x[$, I think $c$ should be as big as possible, but I am not sure what value to pick for $x$.

Comment: You want an approximation for $e = e^1$.

Comment: There is also integral form of the reminder:$$R_k(x) = \int_0^x \frac{f^{(k+1)} (t)}{k!} (x - t)^k \, dt$$ without $c$.  Typically, people consider here $c=\max(x,0)$

Comment: As you know that $\mathrm e\leq 3,6288$ and that $\mathrm e^c\leq \mathrm e$, you have $R_{9}<10^{-6}$ which guarantees a correct result with $n=9$. Your statement is unclear whether the error should be relative of absolute. Here the result is the same in both cases, yet.